# How to compare lines based on a column using awk or grep

Tags: awk, grep, compare, line

I would like to compare my data line by line. Each entry has a copy and some differ in some columns (It is tab delimited). As an example

```
1   0   chrX    121843122   255 16M
1   0   chrX    79062186    250 16M
2   0   chr3    79062186    255 16M
2   0   chr7    79062186    255 16M
3   0   chr3    166649831   255 16M   
3   0   chrX    12345678    255 16M
```

I would like to find out if both of the pair (based on column1) has chrX, the rest of the columns might be different.

In the above example I will only keep (it only matters column 1 to be same and column 3 to be chrX for both.)

```
1   0   chrX    121843122   255 16M
1   0   chrX    79062186    250 16M
```

I wanted to try this in awk but it only seems to work columnwise. How can i implement this using awk or grep?

Comment: you want to filter all lines that are looking like the first one? (Meaning you want to count the occurrences of that line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compares pairs of lines, printing both if the respective field1 and field3 match.

```
awk '{
    prev=$0; f1=$1; f3=$3
    getline 
    if ($1 == f1 && $3 == f3 && $3 == "chrX") {
        print prev
        print
    }
}' filename
```

Comment: but this seems to work if first and third columns are the same. I want first columns to be same and on the third column i am specifically interested in chrX. For example i am not interested in the ones whose column1 are the same and the column 3 is chr1 for example. both of the column 3 should be chrX.

Comment: That's what the `&& $3 == "chrX"` condition is for

Comment: Hi @glennjackman I am having some issues with the code again.